# What is an example of a non-nilpotent finite group $G$ such $C_G(A) \not= A$? $A$ is a maximal normal abelian subgroup of G?

Tags: group-theory

I know that if $G$ is nilpotent then $C_G(A)=A$, where $A$ is a maximal normal abelian subgroup of $G$. I want to see how can this fail to hold in a non-nilpotent group. So far I haven't been able to find an example.

I have checked this for $G=S_3, S_4$ and $A=A_3, V_4$ (Klein $4$-Subgroup), respectively, and these aren't the examples. I wonder if there is an easy example that prove the non-equality.

Comment: Is your question limited to finite groups?

Comment: @SteamyRoot, Yes. Sorry I failed to mention.

Comment: Hint: Consider the product between an abelian group and a non-abelian simple group.

Comment: Another, more involved example, is provided by the [covering groups of the alternating groups $A_n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_groups_of_the_alternating_and_symmetric_groups), for $n \ge 5$ where the centre is not a direct factor.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Thanks. It's obvious to see $A=I \times C_2$ is a maximal abelian normal subgroup of $G=A_5 \times C_2$ and $C_G(A)=G$.

Comment: @Andreas Possibly easier but in the same vein, one can take suitable finite special linear groups.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, you're absolutely right!